# Global object of a class with private constructor

Tags: c++, friend

Is it possible to somehow declare the global scope as a friend of a class?

The problem I am facing is the following:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo() {}
};

Foo foo; //error: 'Foo::Foo()' is private
```

So, what I want is to be able to declare an object of `Foo` at the global scope but not anywhere else.

Note that this question is purely out of interest, I'm not trying to solve an actual problem.

Comment: @Seth: I didn't suppose it would be possible using friends but maybe there is some workaround to get the same behavior.

Comment: You want `singleton` behaviour, and there is planty of methods creating `singleton`'s

Comment: Not necessarily, he just wants to be able to create only global objects. There's no way to do this though because an object can't tell in what scope it's being created.

Comment: @Lol4t0: Well, no. Maybe I want to be able to declare more than one `Foo` object at global scope or declare some other classes/functions as friends and let them be able to also create `Foo` objects.

Comment: @Job if you declare a function as `friend` then it can create those objects even when the ctor is private

Comment: @Seth: Sure, that's what I meant in my previous comment.

Comment: The more important question is, why would you *want* that?

Comment: @Kerrek: Well, as I see it, I can access class members at three different kind of scopes: class scope, function scope or namespace scope (as in this case: the global namespace). It is possible to allow the first two to access private members by using friends but not the third. So I was wondering if there maybe would be a way to do this. But like I said, it is purely out of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do that. You can only name specific classes or functions as friends. It's not possible to make a namespace including the global namespace a friend.

I think the reason there isn't a good work around is that when you define a class or function, only one definition is allowed (not considering overloads, which are really different functions). But, you are allowed to open a namespace as many times as you want and append extra stuff into it each time. So, if you allowed access to a particular namespace, anybody who wanted to could type:

```
namespace TheNamesapceWithAccess
{
  // I've got access to it here too as well as
  // to the original namespace definition that was
  // the only one that was intended to be allowed access.
  // And I could define a function here that allows access the private thing
  // from outside this namespace. I've just subverted the access restriction
  // you intended.
}
```

Comment: True, I was just hoping that somebody would come up with a clever workaround.

Comment: I'm not clever enough. If I could think of a workaround, I would have answered with one. :) But, as far as I know, I think 'no' is the correct answer.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Anyway, I'll wait a little to see if something comes up before accepting your answer.

Comment: I think the reason there isn't a good work around is that when you define a class or function, only one definition is allowed (not considering overloads, which are really different functions). But, you are allowed to open a namespace as many times as you want and append extra stuff into it each time. So, if you allowed access to a particular namespace, anybody who wanted to could type: namespace TheNamesapceWithAccess {  /* I've got access to it here too as well as to the original namespace definition that was the only one that was intended to be allowed access */ }

Comment: That's actually a very good reasoning. Maybe you could add that to your answer?